# Highcharts tickInterval every hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to display data grouped in columns as multiple series. There are three main requirements:

- graph has to start(zero point on X axis) with the fromDate
- there should be a 'tick' on every hour
- toDate is flexible

So far it seems that the tickInterval is very dependent on supplied data and Highchart is ignoring it in some cases such as the one below. Is there a way to make it place ticks in my scenario? Is it possible to add ticks even when there is no data?

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    },
    chart: {
            zoomType: false,
            type: 'column'
        },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        ordinal: false,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
        tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
        minTickInterval: 3600 * 1000
    },

    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0,
                borderWidth: 0,
                grouping: true
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{"name":"One","data":[[1.424304e+12,1],[1.4243076e+12,2],[1.4243148e+12,1],[1.4243301e+12,1],[1.4243364e+12,1],[1.4243436e+12,1],[1.4243472e+12,1],[1.4243526e+12,1],[1.4243535e+12,1],[1.4243544e+12,1],[1.4243625e+12,1],[1.4243652e+12,2],[1.424367e+12,1],[1.4243688e+12,8],[1.4243724e+12,3],[1.4243733e+12,1],[1.424376e+12,8],[1.4243814e+12,3],[1.4243841e+12,1]]},{"name":"Two","data":[[1.424304e+12,1],[1.4243112e+12,1],[1.4243292e+12,1],[1.4243436e+12,1],[1.4243616e+12,1],[1.4243652e+12,3],[1.4243724e+12,1],[1.4243868e+12,1]]},{"name":"Seven","data":[[1.4243706e+12,1],[1.4243814e+12,1]]}]
});
```

Link to the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qn6romsf/3/)

Comment: You have irregular interval between points, so Highcharts can't really calculate proper distance between points. That causes problem with interval on xAxis - workaround is to set `pointRange` for example to 1/10 of hour: http://jsfiddle.net/qn6romsf/7/ - if you can't set `pointRange`, then try to use [`tickPositioner`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner).

Comment: That actually did the trick! All my data is displayed in 15 minute intervals, so setting pointRange to 3600 * 1000 / 4 solved the problem I was having. Post it as an answer, so I can give you credit for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have irregular interval between points, so Highcharts can't really calculate proper distance between points. That causes problem with interval on xAxis - workaround is to set `pointRange` for example to 1/10 of hour: jsfiddle.net/qn6romsf/7 - if you can't set `pointRange`, then try to use [`tickPositioner`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner).

Answer (score -1):

The official demo : [http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update](http://highcharts%20Demo%20of%20dynamic%20update).

Maybe my sample will help you. The logic is next: 1)send ajax to retrieve data every minute(60 elements) 2) push from that list one element to series 3) so chart updates every second.

```
function getLoadApp(){
    var d;
    var ar=[];
    for(var i=0; i<60; i++){
        ar[i] = 0;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./dashboard",
        async: false,
        data: {
            ajax: true,
            oper: "loadapp"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            d = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            for(var i=0; i<d.length; i++){
                ar[Number(d[i].SEC)] = Number(d[i].COUNT); 
            }
            loadappOneMin = loadappOneMin.concat(ar);
        }
    });
}

getLoadApp();
    $('#loadapp').highcharts({
        lang: {
            noData : "На данный момент данные отсутствуют"
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderRadius: 4,
            borderColor: '#E8E8E8',
            events: {
                load: function() {
                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];

                    //каждую сек выталкиваем 1ый из списка
                    setInterval(function() {
                        loadappOneSec = loadappOneMin.shift();
                        if(! loadappOneSec){
                                loadappOneSec = 0;
                        };
                        d = new Date();
                        var x = d.getTime();
                        series.addPoint([x, loadappOneSec], true, true);
                    }, timeInterval);
                    //каждую мин обн.-ем список
                    setInterval('getLoadApp()', 60*timeInterval);    
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'ПТК АЦСК'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: pixelInterval
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'запросов/сек.'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return  Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                pointStart: 0,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
                data: (function() {
                    var data = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;
                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: loadappOneSec
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()
            }]
    });
```